# How to trigger a function if a child element from a div contains a string within its Id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to trigger a certain behavior whenever a certain child element contains at least a string specified by a function. The code I'm using is this:

```
<div id="myDIV" class="mystyle">
<script> /*some script goes here*/ </script>
<div id="asdkmasdp_123123"> 
<!--This DIV was created dynamically (not always) by the script before -->
Contingent DIV
</div>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction(){
if($("#myDIV").find("div[id*='masdp']").length)(function (){
    alert("This works!");
  });
}
myFunction();
</script>
```

As the example states, the child DIV isn't always present (only the 'script' is). When it is I'd like it to trigger something, in this case the browser alert.

I haven't found the right way to do it yet since I'm mostly restricted by the child DIV not being in the DOM when the page finished loading, but only after some user interaction.

Also, the ID and class of the child DIV vary every single time they are created. Note I don't have any access to the 3rd party JS creating this DIV, only to its #myDiv container.

Comment: Check out `MutationObserver` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `MutationObserver` to watch for `subtree` and `childList` modifications on `#myDiv`, and check for the eeement in its callback:

```js
// Set up the observer
var ob = new MutationObserver(function() {
  // See if it exists now
  if ($("#myDiv [id*='masdp']").length) {
    console.log("Found it!");
  }
});
ob.observe($("#myDiv")[0], {
  childList: true,
  subtree: true
});

// Randomly add the element later
setTimeout(function() {
  $("#myDiv").append(
    "<span id='masdpxxx'>masdp</span>"
  );
}, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 200);
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! With some modifications this worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think `MutationObserver` isn't needed here, simple interval will fit enough.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/cdbwy6Lj/3/

HTML div which we are will be watching:

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

JS code to check if div with specified id exists:

```
// Add text after 2 seconds to "sample" div
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#myDiv').append('<div id="asdkmasdp_123123">hello world!</div>');
}, 2000);

// Cache handler to element
var el = $('#myDiv');

// Check every one second if div content contains phrase "world!"
var check = function() {
  if (el.find("[id*='masdp']").length) {
      alert('It works!');
      console.log('It works!');
  } else {
      setTimeout(check, 1000);
  }
};
check();
```

Comment: never do this at home :)

Comment: I modified it to use `setTimeout` but I know that `setInterval` would not be a issue here.

Comment: Thanks, this works well with the div's content but I need it to work with the ID. I triedthe following but it isn't working. 

'<script>
    var el = document.getElementById('myDIV');
    var check = function() {
    if($("#myDIV").find("div[id*='masdp']").length)(function (){
        alert("This works!");
      });
    else {
        setTimeout(check, 250);
    }
    check();
</script>'

Comment: While an interval *will* work, I don't see any reason to prefer it over something that only runs in response to a change that might actually do what's desired.

Comment: I rewrited my code, now it should be more what you need https://jsfiddle.net/cdbwy6Lj/3/

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I was convinced about poor performance of `MutationObserver` but maybe I should revised my opinion. Nevertheless my code is some other way of doing "this", maybe OP or someone else will find it useful.

Comment: @ofca: You're probably thinking of the old mutation *events*, which did indeed have performance issues, which is why they were deprecated and mutation observers created.